# Convert NSString back to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I am using `NSDateFormatter` to convert the current date to a string (in the format: `February 16, 2013`). How can I convert this string back to a `NSDate` object?

```
NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date] dateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

The problem appears to be that the month is written out (`February` vs. `02`), and other questions only explain to use `NSDateFormatter` with a format such as `MM-dd-yyyy`, which I do not believe is possible here. Must I parse this date manually, convert `February` to `02`, and go from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dateFromString of the same NSDateFormatter class to perform backward conversion.
To make it work you need to define dateStyle, so parser will know how text string should be parsed. For the date style that you provided code below will work:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"February 16, 2013"];

NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Comment: `dateFromString` returns a null object when passed a string such as `February 16, 2013`.

Comment: Be sure that you set a proper date style for parser. Code below works for the date that you provided:

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"February 16, 2013"];
    
NSLog(@"%@", date);

Comment: Btw you can mark my answer as THE answer if it is really solved your problem :)

Comment: This answer will fail if run on a device with a locale that uses a language other than English or a different pattern for the long date style.

Comment: Yeah. He asked particular case, used is as a test.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to use localized date formats, you should go with templates

```
 NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date]
                                                       dateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle
                                                       timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

NSLog(@"%@", dateString);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MMMdY"
                                                             options:0
                                                              locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a fixed format that you wish to parse, you must setup the date formatter with the locale of `en_US_POSIX`. Then you must set he date format to `MMMM dd, yyyy`. This will pare any date string that has the full month name, the month day, a comma, then the four-digit year.